# Permission to get read/write access for a file from parent Windows System in Ubuntu app

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, ubuntu-18.04

I have installed Ubuntu app from Microsoft app store in my Windows 10 OS. I am trying to access a file from parent OS . But it's telling like permission denied in Ubuntu terminal. We know from Ubuntu we can give access by issuing command `sudo chmod 777` . But the desired file is in parent Os. how to give permission from windows OS ?

Comment: How do you mean? I have created /mnt/c and a mounting point for accessing my C:-drive, I have no issue while accessing any file on my PC. Can you show the content of /mnt, and the result of `df -hk`?

Comment: hi, I am totally new to ubuntu. As per my app development, I need to access some files in Ubuntu app from Parent Windows 10 OS. Could please help me in this

Comment: I've been struggling quite a bit to get it working on my computer. I managed getting it to work, using a mounting point, as you can see in this `mount` result excerpt: `C: on /mnt/c type drvfs (rw,noatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,case=off)`.